# Cargar vídeo en un segundo exacto

Tags: javascript, video

Buen día, estoy haciendo una plataforma dónde quiero servir vídeos en diferente calidad, ya los tengo en todas las resoluciones que necesito, pero ahora no sé como podría escoger el vídeo y que el nuevo vídeo cargado empieze en el segundo que se quedó en la otra resolución

Comment: Bienvenido Angel, te invito a echar un vistazo a [ask] y [mcve]. ¿Podrías poner el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero que te sirva, Para poder reproducir un video desde un segundo exacto puedes usar una funcion como la siguiente usando vid.setCurTime:

```
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
function setCurTime() { 
vid.currentTime=5 //tiempo en segundos;
} 
</script>
```

y añadir el evento onplay a tu etiqueta de video, aqui un ejemplo:

```
<video id="myVideo" onplay="setCurTime()"  width="320" height="176" 
controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support HTML5 video.

</video>
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, lucho, no era exactamente a lo que me refiero. Lo que quiero hacer es que al darle click a un botón x cambie ma calidad del vídeo, algo como lo que hace YouTube al cambiar sus resoluciones

Comment: Ya tienes la función para cambiar la resolución ?, o necesitas un reproductor ya hecho como https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/HTML5-Video-Player-Resolution-Selector-jQuery-Videre.html